# Supersede c++ library printed lines

Tags: c++

I have a c++ application, where I link my main.cpp with some pre-built libraries (.a files, I dont know their internal details). The main program looks something like this:

```
int main() {
    printf("..this is my part of the code.\n");
    // other code here
}
```

Then when I run my application, it produces the following output, where the first line comes from the linked library:

```
Welcome to product XYZ, version 1.2
..this is my part of the code.
```

As an experiment, I added an "exit(0)" as the first line in my main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    exit(0);
    printf("..this is my part of the code.\n");
    // other code here
}
```

And I got this as the output:

```
Welcome to product XYZ, version 1.2
```

My question is, how does the linked library start printing even before the first line of my code gets executed? What would be the code in the library (an example), which would make that behavior? And secondly, if I want my line to be printed ***before*** the library line, how would I go about doing it?

(Note: the subject line for this question may not match the exact question that I am asking, I was not sure how to frame the subject line to summarize my question. Apologies for that in advance.)

Comment: In C++, code can be executed before the `main` entry point for various reasons.  Global objects are an example, where their constructors are called before `main` executes.

Comment: For instance, objects with [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) are constructed before `main` begins execution and destroyed after `main` returns. If you print in the constructor of such an object, it will print before anything you do in `main`.

Comment: Global variables will always be initialized before the `main` function is called. Though that's not a good way to do it because of the static initialization order fiasco, due to the initialization order between *translation units* is not defined (i.e. there's no guarantee that standard output is correctly setup when you attempt to print). Other than that depending on your compiler there might be special attributes or pragmas that allow code to be run as part of "construction" or "initialization". Exactly what's happening with your library we can't really say.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually I think there [are](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) such guarantees specifically for `std::cout` but more generally the hazards of such objects' lifetime are worth pointing out

Comment: @NathanPierson `std::cout` is not magical. `<iostream>` creates a helper `static` variable in each TU it's included in, and the first one of them that's created initializes `cout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone has said in the comments, initializer code for statics and globals is executed before `main()`, and if this code prints a message, you cannot have something in `main()` supersede it. Suppose your main program is in `main.cc`, as you have it, and the library has a single file, `thing.cc`, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class Thing {
public:
  Thing() { std::cout << "Welcome to the Thing." << std::endl; }
};
static Thing _thing;
```

Now, compile this way:

```sh
c++ thing.cc -o thing.o
c++ main.cc thing.o -o main
./main
```

and you'll see the message from Thing appear before you can even exit.

When there is more than one, the *order* of these initializers is implementation-dependent, but they are all guaranteed to happen before `main()` is called.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my 1st question. And for the 2nd, if I also have a static object with a constructor printing something, there is no way I can guarantee that this will be printed before what the libraries are printing, right?

Comment: @R71 right. That's the "initialization order fiasco". You can search for it.

Comment: No, you cannot guarantee your order. The Singleton pattern gives you control of dependency-initialization order across libraries, but even in that case, you can't supersede a library that doesn't depend on you.